Count number of characters per line
How can I effectively count the number of characters per line in a txt file, and then identify which lines have character counts that do not match a specific target number?

do you really actually care about the count, or do you just want to extract lines of a given length? i.e., is the length some result that you need later on, or are you just trying to filter the lines?

awk '{ print length($0), $0 }' but without knowing what you actually want to do with these lines it's difficult to guess how best to formulate a proper answer

What exactly do you mean by "identify" - print or delete or annotate or something else? Always provide concise, testable sample input and expected output in every question. See [ask].

You can read the file line by line and use the ${#var} syntax to get the length of each line:
$ printf '%s\n' 1 22 333 | while IFS= read -r line ; do echo ${#line} ; done
1
2
3


IFS= clears the IFS variable, making read not throw away trailing whitespace;
-r doesn't interpret backslashes as escapes.

For example, to get line numbers of lines whose length isn't 80, you can use
... | while IFS= read -r line ; do echo ${#line} ; done | grep -vn '^80$'

grep -v '^80$' prints lines that don't contain the sole number 80, -n prefixes them with line numbers.
This tends to be slow, though. Perl is much faster:
$ printf '%s\n' 1 22 333 | perl -lne 'print length'
1
2
3

If you really mean characters and you expected UTF-8 input, you need to run perl with -CI (otherwise e.g. ů would be counted as two characters). It makes Perl about 4 times slower, but still about 80 times faster than the while loop in bash.
To list line numbers of those lines whose length isn't 80, you can use
perl -lne 'print $. if 80 != length'


-l removes newlines from input;
-n runs the code for each input line;
$. is the current input line number;
length is obvious, I guess.


I am trying to use bash for this. Do you know how to list the lines where the length isn't 80 characters using Bash?

@Mare_13: See the update.

Well, I am kind of doing this just as an exercise to practice and learn Bash. So yes, I guess I want to find a way to do it in Bash. Also, the lines I am working on are just long sequences of vowels (the regular English vowels), so I shouldn't have a problem with what you mentioned.

@Mare_13: If you're just using English vowels, your problem is the bash loop is about 320× slower than Perl.

Just counting characters in a small sample file I get 0m0.027s for the bash loop, 0m0.017s for perl, and 0m0.013s for awk  '{print length}' file ... Plus the perl version seems to count the newlines as well, bash & awk only the letters.

@Mare_13 I'll point out that for any tool, be it a hammer, a chisel, a car or a shell, to learn how to use it also encompasses when to not use it. "getting lines with exactly N characters" is literally a single perl, sed, or grep command. In bash, it's complicated and slow. Skill here is seeing that kind of string processing and being "nope, not a job for bash", in my humble opinion.

@tink: You probably didn't use the -l for the Perl version.

Yup, I did. Copy and pasted from your answer. time perl -lne 'print length'  file

@tink That Awk program will return the length of the record, which includes whitespace (not only "letters"). Reading in Bash with read var with the default value of IFS would strip off flanking whitespace. Using read without a variable would not strip flanking whitespace off from the REPLY variable.

And read without -r will discard any backslashes in the input (@Kusalananda)

@tink: Weird. echo . | perl -lne 'print length' prints 1 for me.

I updated the bash example with IFS and -r.

Thanks @Kusalananda for picking that nit; I should have stuck w/ the OP's wording, characters rather than letters. Surely a space is also an ASCII character.

In awk,
awk -v n=80 '
  diff = length - n {
    print "Line "NR" has "(diff > 0 ? "more" : "fewer")" than "n" characters"
  }' < file

In awk, length alone is short for length($0), $0 being the full record being currently processed, records being lines (without their delimiter) by default (RS and ORS, the input and Output Record Separator respectively containing the newline character by default).
That length is meant to be in number of characters, though there are some awk implementations such as mawk (the default in Ubuntu) that are not-multibyte aware and where length() will return the length in bytes instead.  Some awk implementations support only UTF-8 as a multibyte character encoding.
If you want the length to be in bytes regardless of the awk implementation, you can fix the locale to C (LC_ALL=C awk...).
In perl:
perl -lsne 'if ($diff = length($_) - $n) {
              print "Line $. has ".($diff > 0 ? "more" : "fewer")." than $n characters";
            }' -- -n=80 < file

With -n, perl works like sed/awk in that the -expression is interpreted for each record of the input, with the record in $_. By default, records are lines like in sed/awk, but the record delimiter (newline character) is included in $_. That's changed with the -l option with which the delimiter is stripped on input and added back on output like sed/awk do.
By default in perl, text is single byte (and interpreted as being in the ISO8859-1 aka latin1 charset where that matters (not here)), but that can be changed with:

the -C option for I/O to be treated as being UTF-8 encoded as long as long as UTF-8 is the locale's character encoding,
-CSD for all I/O to be UTF-8 regardless of what the locale says,
-Mopen=locale for the input/output to be decoded/encoded as per the character encoding specified in the locale in a similar way as POSIX-compliant awk implementations do.

In perl, like in awk, length alone returns the length of $_ (the record), but length - $n is ambiguous and reported as such by perl as it could be treated as length($_) - $n or length(- $n). (length) - $n or -$n + length or length() - $n remove the ambiguity but we might as well be fully explicit and use length($_) - $n here.

Just for fun; Python one-liner:
$ python <.bashrc -c "
import sys;
print(''.join( [ f'line {n:>4}, {len(line):>4}\n' if len(line)<20 else '' 
                 for n,line in enumerate(sys.stdin) ] ) )"

Line split here, in acceptable format for e.g. Bash, mostly for readability.
len(line)<20 in testing this,
len(line)!=80 for lines that are not 80 characters
A "normal" script might be a tad more readable though:
#!/bin/env python

import sys;

for n,line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
      print( f'line {n:>4}, {len(line):>4}\n' if len(line)<20 else '' )

$ python ./llen2.py <.bashrc - to execute it.
